# Tautulli service won't start after upgrade, pytx timexone error

Tags: ubuntu, python, plex

I have tautulli running on my ubuntu 18.04 plex server. I went to upgrade it using the in browser button. Now the service fails to start:

```
    root@plex:~# systemctl restart tautulli
Job for tautulli.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status tautulli.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@plex:~# 


-- Unit tautulli.service has begun starting up.
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]: Traceback (most recent call last):
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/Tautulli.py", line 38, in <module>
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     import plexpy
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/plexpy/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     import activity_handler
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/plexpy/activity_handler.py", line 24, in <module>
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     import activity_processor
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/plexpy/activity_processor.py", line 21, in <module>
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     import database
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/plexpy/database.py", line 24, in <module>
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     import logger
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/plexpy/logger.py", line 30, in <module>
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     import helpers
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/plexpy/helpers.py", line 48, in <module>
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     from plexpy.api2 import API2
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/plexpy/api2.py", line 39, in <module>
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     import notification_handler
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/plexpy/notification_handler.py", line 43, in <module>
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     from newsletter_handler import notify as notify_newsletter
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/plexpy/newsletter_handler.py", line 29, in <module>
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     NEWSLETTER_SCHED = BackgroundScheduler()
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/lib/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 82, in __init__
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     self.configure(gconfig, **options)
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/lib/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 121, in configure
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     self._configure(config)
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/lib/apscheduler/schedulers/background.py", line 29, in _configure
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     super(BackgroundScheduler, self)._configure(config)
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/lib/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 689, in _configure
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     self.timezone = astimezone(config.pop('timezone', None)) or get_localzone()
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/lib/tzlocal/unix.py", line 131, in get_localzone
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     _cache_tz = _get_localzone()
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/lib/tzlocal/unix.py", line 70, in _get_localzone
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     return pytz.timezone(etctz.replace(' ', '_'))
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:   File "/opt/Tautulli/lib/pytz/__init__.py", line 178, in timezone
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]:     raise UnknownTimeZoneError(zone)
May 04 16:27:22 plex Tautulli.py[25883]: pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'SystemV/EST5'
May 04 16:27:22 plex systemd[1]: tautulli.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 04 16:27:22 plex systemd[1]: tautulli.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 04 16:27:22 plex systemd[1]: Failed to start Tautulli - Stats for Plex Media Server usage.
```

I am not sure how to start looking into this. I am assuming there is some timezone configured in some tautulli config file, and that in turn is not present in `/opt/Tautulli/lib/pytz/__init__.py` ? Or is that fiel itself having an issue?

This answer is linked a lot looking around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21717676/1867249

But his process involves "This will launch a Finder window with your Python modules." and I do not have any GUI installed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with timedatectl, system was using an old timezone SystemV/EST5 for some reason.